# Blazer Server: Setup Braintree Payment Javascript and .NET SDK and API

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, braintree

I was not able to find any examples of setting up Braintree [Javascript](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3) and [.NET](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_dotnet) SDK with Blazer Server application.

Brainstree workflow is to collect user credit card data in the client, which then returns a token, which Braintree calls a Nonce. This way the user's credit card data never passed thru or stored in your application. You pass the nonce to the server, which then process the payment.

I am not sure how to make the javascript work with Blazer server and then what needs to be done on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the payment processes working with Braintree sandbox.

The example is located: https://github.com/MSIH/Blazor-Braintree-Example/

1. Add Braintree javascript library to _Host.cshtml file

```js
<!-- braintree-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.29.0/js/dropin.js">
</script>

</head>
```

2. Add Braintree functions to _Host.cshtml file (this should go in separate js file)

```js
<script>
window.brainstreePayment = (clientToken, dotNetObject) => {
    //alert(clientToken);
    var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
    braintree.dropin.create({
        authorization: clientToken,
        selector: '#dropin-container'
    }, function (err, instance) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (requestPaymentMethodErr, payload) {
                if (requestPaymentMethodErr) {
                    // No payment method is available.
                    // An appropriate error will be shown in the UI.
                    console.error(requestPaymentMethodErr);
                    return;
                }      
                dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('MakePayment', payload.nonce);
            });
        })
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

3. create Payment.razor file

```cs
@page "/PaymentSubmit/"

@using Braintree;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@inject ILogger<Counter> logger;


<label for="Amount">In the Amount:</label>
<input id="Amount" name="Amount" type="tel" min="1" @bind="@Amount" />
<br>
<br>

<div id="dropin-container"></div>

<div id="dropin-wrapper">
    <div id="checkout-message"></div>
    <div id="dropin-container"></div>
    <button id="submit-button">Pay</button>
</div>
<br>
PaymentTransactionId: @PaymentTransactionId
<br>

@code {

   
    public string ClientToken { get; set; }   
    public string Nonce { get; set; }   
    public string Amount { get; set; }    
    public string PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }    

    public BraintreeGateway gateway = new BraintreeGateway
    {
        Environment = Braintree.Environment.SANDBOX,
        MerchantId = "GetFromBraintree",
        PublicKey = "GetFromBraintree",
        PrivateKey = "GetFromBraintree"
    };


    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            ClientToken = gateway.ClientToken.Generate();
            var dotNetReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);        
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("brainstreePayment", ClientToken, dotNetReference);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable("MakePayment")]
    public void MakePayment(string Nonce)
    {

        logger.LogWarning(Nonce);
        logger.LogWarning(Amount);
        decimal newAmount = Convert.ToDecimal(Amount);
        var request = new TransactionRequest
        {
            Amount = newAmount,
            PaymentMethodNonce = Nonce,
            Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
            {
                SubmitForSettlement = true
            }
        };

        Result<Transaction> result = gateway.Transaction.Sale(request);
        if (result.IsSuccess())
        {
            Transaction transaction = result.Target;
            logger.LogWarning("transaction success");
            PaymentTransactionId = transaction.Id;
            StateHasChanged();

            @*redirect*@
        }
        else if (result.Transaction != null)
        {
            @*redirect*@
            logger.LogWarning("transaction null");
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessages = "";
            foreach (ValidationError error in result.Errors.DeepAll())
            {
                errorMessages += "Error: " + (int)error.Code + " - " + error.Message + "\n";
            }
            logger.LogWarning("transaction error");
            logger.LogWarning(errorMessages);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for posting this, it was extremely helpful